# 如何了解「喜欢你，我也是」里写这个替代“秒怂”的词？

Tags: meaning-in-context, characters

我在看着书时遇到了下面不认识的字：

> [image: “呃，那个……”张侃侃听到“学姐”二字，秒？。她舔舔嘴唇尴尬地说，……]
> “呃，那个……”张侃侃听到“学姐”二字，**秒～**。她舔舔嘴唇尴尬地说，……
> <sub>*喜欢你，我也是*，12页</sub>

我无法输入这个词：除了我的手机，我也尝试用[QHanzi](https://www.qhanzi.com/)和[Chinese Input](https://chineseinput.net/handwriting.html)，可是都不能识别“秒”右边的那个字。

为了对比，下面是Kindle版的相同部分。奇怪的是，那两词不一样。

> [image: “呃，那个……”张侃侃听到“学姐”二字，秒怂。她舔舔嘴唇尴尬地说，……]
> “呃，那个……”张侃侃听到“学姐”二字，**秒怂**。她舔舔嘴唇尴尬地说，……
> <sub>*喜欢你，我也是*，Kindle版</sub>

鉴于书里的语境，我猜这个词是“目瞪口呆”类似的意思，可是我根本不知道为什么出现不同。我也不知道“秒怂”是不是正确的词：在词典上我找不到这个词。

**问题**：如何了解「喜欢你，我也是」里写这个替代“秒怂”的词？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you're not going to be happy with this, but I'm going to write up an answer in English. First, at least.

---

First about digitization:

Amazon has the same problem you do. They don't know how to render the character. I haven't looked into it very deeply but it looks like they have issues with CJKV extensions. (Perhaps CJK Ext. A is more doable, but I'm not sure about B-G.)

(⿸尸从) is a CJK Ext. C character.

CJK Ext. characters usually need special font support and that clearly hasn't been implemented into Amazon or Kindle products.

---

can be found in Mandarin dictionaries:

*Pleco*

> weak and incompetent

*Oxford*

> weak by nature

*CC-CEDICT*

> weak and incompetent

Perhaps the most well known word with this character is: 包.

---

For the sake of understanding you can consider 秒 two "words," instead of one single word.

*MDBG*

> 秒
> (coll.) instantly

"秒 + verb" has become a trend in neologisms. There are quite a few of these combinations, think: 秒懂，秒回，秒赞，秒睡，秒删, etc. 秒 is a combination of "instant" + "cower."

Comment: Clearly there is a rendering issue. I the characters in your answer are crossed boxes on my phone. Anyway, I know what you are talking about. Base on the genre, I bet the author probably wrote 怂 in the electrical version, and then when sent to print, the publisher corrected it to the proper character.

Comment: If you’re on Android you could probably install the correct supporting fonts. If you’re on iOS you’re probably out of luck. But, on both devices, you can copy and paste it into an app like Pleco and as long as you have extended fonts installed you’ll be able to render and look it up inside the app. I’ve seen paper dictionaries with proper characters written out painstakingly, but the digital copy from Amazon or Google with the proper characters butchered into something else.

Comment: To my surprise this character isn't listed even in Wenlin, which has a very large etymological corpus from several sources (including the 说文解字). Not under the 尸 radical, and not under the 从 radical. It doesn't even recognize song2 as valid pinyin...!

Comment: @blackgreen  is in Chinese dictionaries like 规范 and MoE, tho.

Answer (score 1):

秒怂：become chicken immediately

秒: Second, here means within a second, or immediately.

Its most original usage is in the word 秒杀, killed immediately. This is a word used in gaming so kill means pass a game stage or win a battle game. So later on 秒杀 means "solved immediately". For example, A: how was your exam? B: 秒杀。

Also see 秒懂 understand immediately, 秒过 pass (interview) immediately.

怂 (adj) ,chicken, cowardly.

From BaiduPedia

> 怂是一个汉字，读音为sǒng，基本释义：1.〔～恿〕鼓动别人去做某事；2.惊，惊惧。 **网络用语中，该字又被用作“㞞”（sóng ）的讹借字，义“讽刺人软弱无能”。**

Based on the explanation, 㞞 is the correct character. And 從 is 从, so the paper copy is correct. Most people just don't know it and substitute by 怂 which have a similar pronunciation.

This character is mostly a dialect, and then used a lot on web. I heard this word in conversations maybe after 2013 or 14, and never really read or write it at that time. I bet most people are the same as me. When typing it, just type "song" and use the most plausible one, mostly because of the 心 part. Interestingly, the Google pinyin input method even does not have the character 㞞.

Here in the fiction, I guess it mean he became chicken immediately and not brave anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The usage in your context is an Internet Slang where it reads sóng，meaning *cower*.  E. g.  上啊，别怂啊！完了，他开始怂了！

Sometimes, it's used as an adjective.  E. g.  怂人